# How do i map my model and dto using this particular mapper?

Tags: c#, api, dotnet-httpclient, dto, mapper

I am trying to map the response of an api call. What I've done is deserialize the response of the API call (the response is an array) into a model, and then return a new dto using the rootobject's data.

```
public class RoadStatusService : IRoadStatusService
    {
        string baseURL = "blah";

        private readonly IMapToNew<Road, RoadDto> _mapper;

        public RoadStatusService()
        {

        }

        public RoadStatusService(IMapToNew<Road, RoadDto> mapper)
        {
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        public RoadDto GetRoadStatusDetail()
        {
            var road = CallApi();


            return new RoadDto
            {
                DisplayName = road.Result.DisplayName,
                StatusSeverityDescription = road.Result.DisplayName,
                StatusSeverity = road.Result.DisplayName
            };
        }


        private async Task<Road> CallApi()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseURL);

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync(baseURL);

            if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var roadResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                List<Road> road = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Road>>(roadResponse);


                foreach (var item in road)
                {
                    return new Road
                    {
                        DisplayName = item.DisplayName,
                        StatusSeverity = item.StatusSeverity,
                        StatusSeverityDescription = item.StatusSeverityDescription
                    };
                }

            }

            return null;
        }


    }
```

My question is, how can I use a mapper class to map my model to my dto object without having to do this:

```
    public RoadDto GetRoadStatusDetail()
    {
        var road = CallApi();


        return new RoadDto
        {
            DisplayName = road.Result.DisplayName,
            StatusSeverityDescription = road.Result.DisplayName,
            StatusSeverity = road.Result.DisplayName
        };
    }
```

I've written a mapperclass and an interface to do this, but I just can't get it to work :

```
public class RoadToRoadDtoMapper : IMapToNew<Road, RoadDto>
{
    public RoadDto Map(Road model)
    {
        return new RoadDto
        {
            DisplayName = model?.DisplayName,
            StatusSeverity = model?.StatusSeverity,
            StatusSeverityDescription = model?.StatusSeverityDescription
        };
    }
}
```

and:

```
public interface IMapToNew<in TIn, out TOut>
{
    TOut Map(TIn model);
}
```

I think the problem I am having is that the api call responds with an array? I am wondering if I should somehow transform my object to a list and then call `.Select` and use the mapper.map function I have written. I can't get it to work though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, you need a mapper for the lists too and then call the mapper for the objects inside that class:

```
public class RoadListToRoadListDtoMapper : IMapToNew<List<Road>, List<RoadDto>>
{
    private RoadToRoadDtoMapper roadToRoadDtoMapper = new RoadToRoadDtoMapper();
    public List<RoadDto> Map(List<Road> models)
    {
        var roadDtos = new List<RoadDto>();
        foreach(var road in models){
            roadDtos.Add(roadToRoadDtoMapper.Map(road));
        }
        return roadDtos;  
    }
}
```